# One EJS page won't load unless I restart my server

Tags: javascript, arrays, ejs, render

Here's one for you all. FYI, this is all local right now.

I'm building a simple blog site with ejs. Every page can be called and loads perfectly...except for my post page. It stalls and then once I type 'rs' in my terminal to start it (which should clear my post array of any info), it renders! To me this makes no sense because how would it know what to render after the array has been cleared?

I've gone through the code a couple times, but I figured I would reach out to you fine people to help me out.

Any ideas?

Here is my code

...

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const ejs = require("ejs");
const _ = require("lodash");

const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.static("public"));

//global post array

let posts =[];


//home logic

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  res.render("home", {
    startingContent:homeStartingContent,
    posts: posts} );
});

// about logic

app.get("/about", function (req, res) {
  res.render("about", {aboutContent:aboutContent});
  
});

//contact logic

app.get("/contact", function (req, res) {
  res.render("contact", {contactContent:contactContent});
  
});

//compose logic

app.get("/compose", function (req, res){
 
  res.render("compose");


});


app.post('/compose', function(req, res) {

const postContent = {
  title: req.body.postTitle,
  content: req.body.postBody
}; 

posts.push(postContent);

res.redirect("/")


});

//Routing Parameters

app.get("/posts/:postName", function(req, res){
 
const requestedTitle = _.lowerCase(req.params.postName);

posts.forEach(function(post){

const storedTitle = _.lowerCase(post.title);
   
  if (storedTitle === requestedTitle) {
    res.render("post", {
      title: post.title,
      content: post.content
    });
  };
  
});


});


app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log("Server started on port 3000");
});
```

...

my post.ejs code

...

```
<%- include('partials/header'); -%>

<h1><%=title%></h1>
<p><%=content%></p>



<%- include('partials/footer'); -%>
```

..

Comment: What happens when `storedTitle === requestedTitle` is `false`?

Comment: It would default to the standard error page, but let me try adding an else statement. Maybe that will fix it. :)

Comment: Dima, I added an else statement with a simple console.log("No Match Found"), and the results were the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to first finish the iteration and find (or not) the related post. After that, if it is **not** found, you still have to send something as a response:

```js
app.get("/posts/:postName", (req, res) => {
  const requestedTitle = _.lowerCase(req.params.postName);
  const post = posts.find((post) => _.lowerCase(post.title) === requestedTitle);

  if (post) {
    res.render("post", {
      title: post.title,
      content: post.content
    });
  } else {
    // of course, you must have error page for this to work
    res.status(404).render("error", {
      message: `Post "${requestedTitle}" not found`,
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I removed the loop from the code and instead create two constants that satisfied my requirements. This code was suggested to me by a colleague.

```
app.get("/posts/:postName", function (req,res) {
  const requestedTitle = _.lowerCase(req.params.postName);
  
  //Put the req.params.postName constant into a new constant instead of 
  putting it in a loop.
  const storedTitle = posts.filter((post) => (
    _.lowerCase(post.title) === requestedTitle)
  );
    //reroute to homepage
    if (storedTitle.length === 0) {
      res.redirect('/');
     //otherwise render the page that was called
    } else {
      res.render('post', {
        title: storedTitle[0].title,
        content: storedTitle[0].content
      })
    }

})
```